# "Strappare qualcosa coi denti": si tratta di un modo di dire?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *L’amore ai tempi del Covid-19*<sup>1</sup>, di Antonio Manzini,  ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ci fu l'esplosione dei tuttologi in televisione e sui social. Gente che **aveva strappato la licenza liceale coi denti** si improvvisò infettivologo, dicendo la sua sulla natura del Covid-19. Teorie mediche parlavano di vaccini e medicinali miracolosi: sieri antivipera sconfiggevano il contagio, impacchi di saliva di mucca lo fermavano per sempre, una masturbazione compulsiva e selvaggia lo indeboliva, il Frascati bianco Est! Est!! Est!!! scioglieva la corona del virus e rendeva immuni i bimbi sotto i 6 mesi.

La mia domanda è sul significato e uso dell'espressione "strappare qualcosa (nel testo, la licenza liceale) coi denti" che appare in questo passaggio. Si tratta di qualche sorta di modo di dire, frase fatta o espressione idiomatica?

Ho cercato alla voce "strappare" di alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata. Non appare neanche sul dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli.

Su questo [sito web](http://www.orticalab.it/Un-derby-strappato-coi-denti-un), ne ho trovato un altro esempio, però (anche qui il grassetto è mio):

> Un derby **strappato coi denti**, un terzo posto meritato: un anno dopo questa Sidigas è ancora grande

Dal contesto di questo esempio, mi pare che il suo significato sia più o meno "riuscire a stento a fare qualcosa, fare qualcosa con grande difficoltà". Immagino anche che si usi in registri informali. È così?

---

<sup>1. Secondo il [blog di Licia Corbolante](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2020/02/12/nome-malattia-coronavirus-2019-ncov/), che si occupa di ricerca terminologica e qualità linguistica, 
dovrebbe essere "della COVID-19", ma in questo racconto l'autore fa confusione tra virus e malattia.</sup>

Comment: Scusa ma non capisco se stai chiedendo il significato dell’espressione o l’uso che ne viene fatto nell’estratto   che citi. Nel dubbio ho cancellato la mia risposta.

Comment: @Hachi: Sto chiedendo sul significato e uso dell'espressione (in particolare quello che si fa nel passaggio citato).

Comment: @Hachi: Della definizione del Treccani che avevi messo, forse "riuscire a ottenere qualcosa con espedienti" può anche essere il senso di "strappare qualcosa con i denti" in determinati contesti (magari quello del testo della domanda)?

Comment: Potrebbe essere ma non potrei dirlo, il senso dell’espressione rimane comunque lo stesso. Fare di tutto, sforzarsi al massimo per ottenere qualcosa, e usare degli espedienti   è solo uno dei tanti modi per ottenere a tutti i costi qualcosa.  Il giudizio sull’uso dell’espressione nel testo è opinabile, ognuno di noi potrebbe esprimere un'opinione diversa.

Comment: @Hachi:  Cioè, la conclusione sarebbe che non si può sapere qual è il senso dell'espressione nel testo della domanda?

Comment: La conclusione è che il senso è quello di cui abbiamo parlato. Poi se l’espressione è stata usata in senso ironico, spregevole, neuro o altro è una questione di opinioni personali.

Comment: @Hachi: Be', secondo me, che c'è dell'ironia in questo testo è qualcosa molto evidente...

Comment: Secondo me esprime chiaramente disprezzo ...

Comment: @Hachi: Se si può spiegare il senso dell'espressione senza entrare in giudizi opinabili, non capisco perché non si possa dare una risposta alla domanda.

Comment: @Hachi: “Fare di tutto, sforzarsi al massimo per ottenere qualcosa, e usare degli espedienti è solo uno dei tanti modi per ottenere a tutti i costi qualcosa”: non so se è un refuso o quello che volevi dire, ma direi che siano due modi, non uno. Per ottenere una licenza liceale sono modi ben diversi sforzarsi al massimo (nello studio, presumibilmente) e usare espedienti...

Comment: Probabilmente l'autore voleva dire “con le unghie”, cioè l'attrezzo meno adatto, a indicare che il diploma è stato ottenuto in modo avventuroso e con espedienti, invece che con lo studio.

Comment: @egreg:   [Qui](https://www.spazionapoli.it/2014/12/01/punto-strappato-con-le-unghie-e-con-denti/) si trova "punto strappato con le unghie e con i denti".

Comment: @Charo Infatti, ho usato solo “unghie”.

Comment: Sì, @egreg: ricercando con Google, si trovano anche esempi di "strappare con le unghie". Per esempio, [qui](https://www.acspezia.com/news/dadderio-quotrisultato-strappato-con-le-unghie-i-ragazzi-hanno-dato-tuttoquot.3484.html): "Risultato strappato con le unghie; i ragazzi hanno dato tutto". Ma c'è veramente qualche differenza tra "con i denti" e "con le unghie"?

Comment: ***con le unghie e con i denti*** è un modo di dire: *con grande impegno e tenacia, con tutte le forze: difendersi, combattere con le unghie e con i denti* - https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/con-le-unghie-e-con-i-denti  - l’espressione è generalmente usata con verbi come lottare, difendere, combattere e simili. - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=con+le+unghie+e+con+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccon%20le%20unghie%20e%20con%3B%2Cc0

Comment: C'è una risposta da 13 ore, ma senza nessun voto: devo interpretate che il significato di questa espressione è diverso di quello spiegato nella risposta?

Comment: @Hachi: Dal tuo ultimo commento (e anche da quello che ha detto egreg: questi due commenti hanno un voto, quindi immagino siano rilevanti per la risposta), dovrei capire che "strappare coi denti" significa strappare (in senso figurato) con grande impegno e tenacia, con tutte le forze? (Cioè, il significato non è quello spiegato nella risposta?).

Answer (score 1):

Strappare con i denti vuol dire conseguire a fatica, a stento, per il rotto della cuffia, un risultato (come, negli esempi da te fatti, la licenza o la vittoria del derby). Si tratta di un modo di dire abbastanza diffuso anche nel linguaggio parlato ed in quello giornalistico, in particolare sportivo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Non conoscevo il significato dell'espressione   "per il rotto della cuffia", ma ne ho trovato un'interessante spiegazione sul [sito dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/sul-modo-di-dire-per-il-rotto-della-cuffia/56).